# will the jvm look in the registry when trying to find the location of a dll?

Tags: java, dll

My java program is finding a dll to load but I can't figure out how it knows where its location is.    I did a System.getProperty("java.library.path"); in the program and found all the places it is looking but the actual location of the dll is in none of these places.    There is a registry entry for the dll's path but I don't think Java is looking in there, is it?

Any clues would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Elliott

Comment: Depends on dll and how you are using it. If it is an active X server type installed on the machine e.g. word or excel etc then yes. It is is just a hello world dll sitting in your bin directory then not unless you registered through Visual Studio during build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a copy of the dll was on my desktop and now I know that it searches the desktop as well.